# Error while loading data using EmberJS

Tags: json, ember.js

I try to show all data loaded from server using EmberJS.
I have model "node"

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  id: DS.attr(),
  nodeName: DS.attr(),
  address: DS.attr(),
  listeningPort: DS.attr(),
  approved: DS.attr()

});
```

Adapter is

```
import JSONAPIAdapter from 'ember-data/adapters/json-api';

export default JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/v1'
});
```

Also I have index route

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    return this.store.findAll('node');
  }
});
```

When index rote is opened a request is sent to http://localhost:8080/api/v1/nodes which returns JSON

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "address": "127.0.0.1",
            "approved": true,
            "id": 24,
            "listeningPort": 54879,
            "nodeName": "Узел оборудования"
        }
    ]
}
```

Error appears while parsing this JSON

> vendor-c5c8d3d….js:11 Error while processing route: index Cannot read property 'type' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Your response isn't json-api compliant. See [json-api](http://jsonapi.org) for more details.

basically, you need your response to look something like this:

```
{
  "data": [{
    "type": "nodes",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "node-name": "head",
      "address": 42,
      "listening-port": 11117,
      "approved": true
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: Error was that I used wrong adapter.
It shoulbe 
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/v1'
});

Comment: Ah, guessing you went with JSONAdapter or RESTAdapter then?